# VBA - Applying border around the areas with value/text

Tags: excel, vba

The code that I am currently using:

```
Dim border As Range
Dim brng As Range

Set border = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each brng In border
brng.BorderAround _
    LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
    Weight:=xlThin
End If
Next brng
```

The screenshot on the left is what I currently get, and the screenshot on the right is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Maybe : `for each brng in activesheet.columns(2).specialcells(xlconstants).areas: brng.offset(0, -1).resize(brng.rows.count, 5).borderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin: next`. Not tested.

Comment: @karma it still doesn't pick up as I use `Sheets("BP").Select` just before it.

Comment: Please ignore the sheets BP select for the time being..... check if `for each brng in activesheet.columns(2).specialcells(xlconstants).areas: brng.offset(0, -1).resize(brng.rows.count, 5).SELECT: next`, does it give you a correct selection ? Or try `for each brng in activesheet.columns(2).specialcells(xlconstants).areas: brng.SELECT: next` if it select correctly. Step run (press F8) the code.

Comment: If the code(s) below are currently not working, then this is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please add further code for context and so people can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BorderAround is just put a border within the specified range.

If the original data has no border at all and you expect a result as in your right side of the image, then need to apply horizontal, vertical, etc.

```
Sub test()
For Each brng In ActiveSheet.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlConstants).Areas
With brng.Offset(0, -1).Resize(brng.Rows.Count, 5)
    .select '---> use to check when in debug mode if the range is correct, remove this line later on
    .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try the next way:

```
Sub BorderArroudAreas()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, rngBord As Range, arrBord, El, A As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on B:B
   
   Set rng = sh.Range("B1:B" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'the B:B discontinuous range (empty rows is a delimiter for the range areas)
   
   'obtain a range having the same areas in terms of rows, but all used range columns:
   Set rngBord = Intersect(rng.EntireRow, sh.UsedRange.EntireColumn)
   
   'create an array with numbers from 7 to 12 (the borders type constants...)
   arrBord = Application.Evaluate("Row(7:12)") 'used to place cells borders
   
   For Each A In rngBord.Areas 'iterate between the range areas
        For Each El In arrBord 'place borders on each area cells:
             With A.Borders(El)
                   .LineStyle = xlContinuous: .Weight = xlThin: .ColorIndex = 0
             End With
         Next El
   Next A
End Sub
```

It should be faster even for large ranges, not placing borders **for each cell**...

Comment: @TK4795 Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working but you're not excluding blank rows from your loop which means all cells in your `UsedRange` get a border. You should add a check for blank rows and exclude those from getting borders.

```
Dim border As Range
Dim brng As Range

Set border = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each brng In border
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(brng.EntireRow) > 0 Then
        brng.BorderAround _
            LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
            Weight:=xlThin
    End If
Next brng
```

I see you have an `End If` in your code already, not sure where you begin your `If`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't put the border around anything.